# Conditional validation for a form inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, formvalidation-plugin

Starting off there is a append button that generates a row with 1 select box, 1 inputbox, and 4 checkboxes. The limit of adding this would be 1-10 rows at max. I have no idea how to make a jquery validation using for example http://formvalidation.io/ - or a standalone jquery code. The rules I would like to apply:

If the role chosen is user (not an admin) , I must validate that there is at least one checkbox checked and the user doesn't appears twice in the selections

The thing is I don't even know where to start from, can you point me any hints?

**Live example ::** http://jsfiddle.net/Yy2gB/131/

Append method onClick

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var obj = {"1":"Admin istrator","2":"User2"};

    //$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    $(".addCF").click(function(){

        count = $('#customFields tr').length + 1;
        var sel = $('<select name="user'+count+'">');

        for(key in obj){
            // The key is key
            // The value is obj[key]
            sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',key).text(obj[key]));
        }

        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        $("#customFields").append('<tr><td>'+sel[0].outerHTML
        +'</td><td><input class="form-control" class="valid_role"'
        +' data-fv-field="emails" type="text" name="role'+count
        +'" /></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox"'
        +' name="can_edit'+count+'"></td><td><input type="checkbox" '
        +'class="mycheckbox" name="can_read'+count+'"></td><td><input '
        +'type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="can_execute'+count+'">'
        +'</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" '
        +'name="is_admin'+count+'"></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);"'
        +'class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
        $('.mycheckbox').iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue'
        });
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });
    $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

HTML Form

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12"> 
  <table class="table table-user-information" id="customFields">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="standardTable_Header">User</th>
        <th class="standardTable_Header">Role</th>
        <th class="standardTable_Header">
          <span title="administrator projektu">Can read</span>
        </th>
        <th class="standardTable_Header">
           <span title="uprawnienie do edycji danych projektu">
             edit
           </span>
        </th>
        <th class="standardTable_Header">
          <span title="uprawnienie do odczytu danych projektu oraz przypisanych do niego zadań">
           excute
          </span>
        </th>
        <th class="standardTable_Header">
          <span title="uprawnienie do edycji danych projektu">
            admin
          </span>
         </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addCF">
      Append
    </button>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and through [this demo](http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/#example:-makes-%22parent%22-required-only-if-age-is-below-13), We could do the following:
**Assumption**: Roles check boxes must have at least one checked if - and only if - the `select` tag have the value `User2`
1- wrap your table with `form` tag that has a submit button:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <form id="myform">
        <table class="table table-user-information" id="customFields">
            ...
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

2- We need to edit the checkboxes html to make them all have the same name but with different values, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="ourRoles" value="can_edit' ...>
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="ourRoles" value="can_read' ...>
```

and so on.
3- Add the following script:

```
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
        success: "valid"
    });
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            ourRoles: {
                required: function () {
                    if ($("select[name=user2]").val() == 2) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

See all together with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lghajh0r/3/)

Comment: This is working only for one append, if its dynamic it wont validate the other fields besides it also needs to check if there is atleast one checkbox checked and the user doesn't appears twice in the selections - so I guess this method wont solve this

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but your question was `The thing is I don't even know where to start from, can you point me any hints?` so I gave you a hint and showed you how to start. Complete your project based on my answer and show some effort. If you want help I do exist for helping you :)

Comment: See this question. it's important to know how questions and answers should be in SO http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276963/answering-questions-give-solution-or-point-them-in-the-right-direction